# Grails checkbox simple question

Tags: grails, checkbox

I have this checkBox in my view inside a form:

```
<g:checkBox name="myCheckbox" value="${false}" />
```

In my controller, I how do I know if it is checked or not?

I tried:

```
if(!params.myCheckbox)
// obviously not,  because it will always be true

if(params.myCheckBox.checked)
// also dont work.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (params.myCheckbox) {
  println "checkbox is checked"

} else {
  println "checkbox is not checked or myCheckbox parameter is missing"
}
```

If you need to separately handle "checkbox is not checked" and "myCheckbox parameter is missing", use:

```
if (params.myCheckBox == null) {
  println "myCheckbox parameter is missing"

} else if (params.myCheckbox) {
  println "checkbox is checked"

} else {
  println "checkbox is not checked"
}
```

Comment: what you mean by "parameter is missing" ?

Comment: it means that it is not present in params map so - if you are submitting form it means that the form doesn't have field called "myCheckbox".

Comment: also try the null-safe single liner? -     params?.myCheckbox

Comment: As @AdilMehmood said: `if (params?.myCheckBox == null)`